# conversion between std::vector and _variant_t

Tags: c++, com, variant, stdvector

I need to convert between `std::vector` and `_variant_t` to avoid looping when writing/sending data into some file (database, Excel, etc.)

Could you please let me know how to proceed with that?

I was trying to get a `std::vector<_variant_t>` and somehow put into another `_variant_t` variable, but direct conversion is not supported and even if it's done there's no either method or some kind of wrapper to get this vector into a `_variant_t` variable.

I would prefer not to deal with any loops.

Comment: Do you really mean `std::vector`? Or do you mean `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: Why the phobia of loops? You should be serialising your vector _data_ properly rather than trying to cram the entire object into some other type; if that's done with a loop, then so be it (though usually it needn't be).

Comment: What does your `std::vector` actually hold?  What `_variant_t` data type do you need to convert to?  Please provide more details.

Answer (score 6):

A `std::vector` and `_variant_t` are incompatible types.  The `_variant_t` type is designed to support scenarios where a COM interface needs to support multiple types of values for the same parameters.  It's set of values is limited to those for which COM understands how to marshal.  `std::vectory` is not one of those types.

The standard way to store a collection of values into a `_variant_t` is to do so as a safe array.  So the easiest solution is to convert the `std::vector` to a safe array and store that in the variant.  There's really no way to avoid a loop here

```
// Convert to a safe array
CComSafeArary<INT> safeArray;
std::vector<int> col = ...;
for (std::vector<int>::const_iteator it = col.begin(); it != col.end(); it++) {
  safeArray.Add(*it);
}

// Initialize the variant
VARIANT vt;
VariantInit(&vt);
vt.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_INT;
vt.parray = safeArray.Detach();

// Create the _variant_t
_variant_t variant;
variant.Attach(vt);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! In my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943360/c-excel-com-getting-a-double-array-back-from-variant-t-zeros-on-even-place I managed to avoid a loop by converting a _vartiant_t object to a regular double std::vector. Is there a similar trick one can use here? The reason I'm asking this is I'm not too familiar with SafeArray-s so unfortunately I do not know if it's possible to play with iterators  the same way as I have done before.

Comment: @Anthony I don't believe there is.

Comment: @ JaredPar:Thank you so much for you valuable help!!! I really appreciate your fast replies!