# What vb6 type is ABI-compatible with std::vector?

Tags: c++, dll, vb6, stdvector

I've been writing a DLL in C++, now I must call this DLL from a VB6 application.

Here's a code sample from this DLL :

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;    

void __stdcall DLLFunction (vector<Object>*)
{
 // performs a few operations on the Objects contained in the vector.
}

struct Object
{
    long CoordX;
    long CoordY;
    long Width;
    long Height;
    LPSTR Id;
};
```

I also defined the "Object struct" in VB6

```
Private Type Object
    CoordX As Integer 
    CoordY As Integer 
    Width As Integer
    Height As Integer
    Id As String 
End Type
```

The issue is I don't know what vb6 type could stand for std::vector in order to call the DLL's function.

Notes :
- I use a vector for the DLL to be able to add objects.
- I use a pointer in order to use as less memory as possible.
- Sorry for my english, it ain't my home language at all.
- Thank you for reading and trying to help me.

**Edit :**
- I fixed the typing issues (Ids are definitely ended by NullChar, so LPSTR should do the trick).
- I read your answers, and I'd like to thank both of you, your answers are close to one another and a major issue remains. My DLL definitely needs to add elements to the container. Thus, I'm wondering how I could do the trick. Maybe I could add a return type to my function and then make that the function is able to return the items it created (instead of putting it directly into the container) so that the vb6 application gets these items and is able to process them, but I can't figure out how to do this

**Edit bis :**

**@Rook :** I feel like I could achieve this by using a new struct.
    struct ObjectArrayPointer
    {
        Object* Pointer;
        size_t Counter;
    }

And then call my function this way :

```
void __stdcall DLLFunction (ObjectArrayPointer*);
```

I would then be able to add objects and edit the size parameter for my VB6 application to find these new objects. Was that what you meant?

Comment: You may find the `Integer` types in your VB6 structure need to be `Long`. `Integer` is only 16 bits in VB6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be trying to export template containers from a DLL anyway. They're likely to break when faced with newer compilers and libraries (eg. a library built under C++03 will not play well with code built using C++11).

The least painful thing to do is to accept a pointer to a buffer and a length parameter,

```
void __stdcall DLLFunction (Object* buffer, size_t nObjects);
```

if the size of the container will not change during execution. This interface is about as simple as it gets, and is easily accessible by any language that understand C calling conventions (eg. almost every single one.)

You've already thrown away most of the use of a `std::vector` because you've already specialised it to `Object`; you could consider going all the way and creating your own `ObjectCollection` class which uses a `std::vector` internally but presents a non-templated interface. Here's a simple example :

```
// In your public API header file:
typedef struct object_collection_t *object_collection;

object_collection CreateObjectCollection();
void DestroyObjectCollect(object_collection collection);
void AddObjectToCollection(object_collection collection, Object* object);
// etc
```

No template types are exposed in any form in the header. This is good.

```
// And the corresponding code file:

struct object_collection_t
{
    std::vector<Object*> objects;
};

object_collection CreateObjectCollection() { return new object_collection_t; }
void DestroyObjectCollect(object_collection collection) { delete collection; }
void AddObjectToCollection(object_collection collection, Object* object)
{
    collection->objects.push_back(object);
}
// etc
```

All of templating code is hidden away, leaving you with a fairly clean and simple interface which present an opaque pointer type that can be passed around by external code but only queried and modified by your own, etc.

EDIT: Incidentally, I've used `Object*` throughout the above code. It may well be safer and impler to use just plain old `Object` and avoid all of the issues associated with memory management and pointer manipulation by client code. If `Object` is sufficiently small and simple, passing by value may be a better approach.

(NB: not checked for compilability or functionality. E&OE. Caveat Implementor!)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but as I stated above, I need to find a way to add elements to the Input, that's why I was searching for another input type than a simple array.

Comment: I just edited my question to make sure I understood what you meant.

Comment: @Illmess: From your edit: yes, you could just use a simple struct including length, but then you are relying on client code not getting it all horribly wrong. By wrapping `std::vector` in the way that I have done, you don't need to trust the VB side to get the length right. All you have to worry about is memory deallocation. You also get to use all of the good features of `std::vector` in the code in your DLL which could make other tasks you need to do a little easier and safer. It is up to you, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as it's a C++ class/template. Internally, it's an array but not in a way that can be created from VB6.

Your best bet is to change the function to accept a pointer to an array with a count parameter.

You'll also need to be very careful as to how the type is structured.

1. C++ `int`s are `Long`s in VB6.
2. Also, the `Id` string won't be compatible. VB6 will have a pointer to a unicode BString (unless you make it fixed length) where as a C++ will have std::string which is an array of ANSI chars. VB6 MAY marshal this if you pass an array of the objects (rather than a pointer)

Comment: Worse, std::string is an array of chars ie an ANSI string while a BString is Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The VB6 ABI is the COM Automation ABI.

Therefore, if you need an arry which is VB6 ABI compatible, you should probably use SAFEARRAY. I suggest you should also be using the Compiler COM Support classes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5yb2sfxk(v=vs.80).aspx

This question appears to do exactly what you want, using ATL's CComSafeArray class:

- [conversion between std::vector and _variant_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261258/conversion-between-stdvector-and-variant-t)

You may also want to look at these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=safearray+_variant_t

**Alternatives to SAFEARRAY**

The alternative to SAFEARRAY is to supply a COM Collection object. This is simply a COM object with a Dispinterface or Dual interface with the methods `Count` and `Item`. Item should have dispid=0 to be the default method. You may also want to supply `_NewEnum` with `DISPID_NEWENUM` to support the For Each syntax.